# Why an API load using Jmeter is not hitting in devops?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, devops

When an API load is send using Jmeter it is not getting hit in devops . The response was correct and response code is 200, also same environment is used for the performance testing purpose.

Expecting - API load hitting in devops and correct response code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what "devops" is and how do you know that "it is not getting hit".

If you can "hit" the API successfully using another tool like your browser, [Postman](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-postman-test-apis) or [cURL](https://curl.se/) and it "gets hit" in "devops" it means that your JMeter test is not configured properly.

In this case the easiest would be either recording the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or generate the request from cURL command line:

[image]

If the API is not getting "hit" when you test it manually most probably the way you're monitoring the "hits" in "devops" is not properly configured